# how to center webview contents in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, centering, feed

***SCREENSHOT***:

https://camo.githubusercontent.com/7c4b76724b703bcded8aafbba9c012542726462c/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f716375554d664a2e706e6725374275726c253744

Hi, is there a way I can center the text and the image of the articles?

**this is the layout file**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/desc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
                android:text="@string/desc" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
package com.iven.lfflfeedreader.mainact;

import com.iven.lfflfeedreader.R;
import com.iven.lfflfeedreader.domparser.RSSFeed;    
import android.os.Bundle;    
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;    
import android.view.LayoutInflater;    
import android.view.View;    
import android.view.ViewGroup;    
import android.webkit.WebSettings;    
import android.webkit.WebView;    
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;    
import android.widget.ScrollView;    
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    private int fPos;    
    RSSFeed fFeed;

    @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        fFeed = (RSSFeed) getArguments().getSerializable("feed");    
        fPos = getArguments().getInt("pos");    
    }

    @Override    
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        View view = inflater    
                .inflate(R.layout.article_fragment, container, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);    
        WebView wb = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.sv);
        sv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);

        // Set webview settings    
        WebSettings ws = wb.getSettings();    
        ws.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        // Set the views    
        title.setText(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getTitle());   
        wb.loadData(fFeed.getItem(fPos).getDescription(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
        return view;    
    }
}
```

the source code of the app is available here

thanks

https://github.com/enricocid/lffl-feed-reader

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
wb.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

This will zoom out and fit the image to your screen and show it in center.

Note: Because the WebView is used to render the scripts and show it in a view, so as long as the source of the web url isn't aligned in center you can't change it. However you can parse the web content and then show them in any customizable way you want.

So far the the github project you are talking about also used the same approach. A html parser called **Jsoup** was used to parse the html contents and showing in a view.

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 19 :)

Comment: Try this, webview.setInitialScale(1);

Comment: I know this answer is rather old, but I keep seeing it given for similar questions. This does **not** center a WebView. It attempts to center the content by zooming the page to where the content fills the view size. Unless you have access to the page code and know exactly how it was made, this can also result in your desired content being a very small box in the center of a very large wallpaper.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem by adding

```
// set image scale to fit screen if larger than screen width
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; // minus some padding values if you have any left/right padding
    Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.id.image);
    int wi = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();

    double scale = (wi>screenWidth) ? (double)screenWidth/wi : 1.0;
    wb.setInitialScale((int) (scale*340));'code'
```

now the image is at the center below the abstract and on top of the article entry...:) gonna push changes later on git. thanks anyway:)

Comment: It appears you were trying to center the view itself. I had a feeling this was the case from the inline content. You could have just as easily used a `gravity` on the WebView in relation to its parent view.